# Unable to open the file Problems were detected in its contents using PhpWord in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am generating a word file in laravel using the phpword library.

All the contents of the word file must be generated from the database.

So when I do the following code :

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $preambule = DB::table('modele_contrat')->select('preambule')->where('id_modele_contrat', $value['id_modele_contrat'])->value('preambule');

    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    $text = $section->addText($preambule);
    $text = $section->addText($value['id_modele_contrat']);
    $text = $section->addText($value['date_fin_contrat']);
  
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('Appdividend.docx');
    
    return response()->download(public_path('Appdividend.docx'));
}
```

The file does not open and shows me the following error in on the file:

> Unable to open the file Problems were detected in its contents

And it is because of the following line:

```
$text = $section->addText($preambule);
```

Comment: Wat is the value of `$preambule` look like? Can you `dd()` this?

Comment: I'm getting the value that I have in database : `"""
ENTRE LES SOUSSIGNES :
, dont le siège social est situé à [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx], inscrite au Registre de Commerce de [Ville] sous le n° [xxx xxx], 
Ci-après l’ « Annonceur », dont le siège social est situé au 5ème étage, Casablanca – Maroc, immatriculée au registre de commerce de Casablanca sous le numéro
"""`